# Warning XMLHttpRequest to ejecute ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Hi everyone I try to execute this request

```
var post_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0716604892";
                var text_area = $('#isbn_textarea').val().trim();
                  $.ajax({
                  dataType: 'json',
                  url: post_url,
                  type: 'GET',
                    success: function(response) {
                      var out = "";
                      alert(response);
                    }, 
                    error: function(response) {
                        alert('mal');
                    }

                })
```

But I obtain this  warning

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding a callback to your url? `...&callback=?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something, somewhere, is setting `async` to `false` and it isn't in the code you've shared.

Most likely you have a call to [`ajaxsetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) somewhere which is setting `async`. You should find it and remove it.

(As a quick hack, you could stick `async: true` in your options object).